# Is it possible to extend `dart:async`s Future class

Tags: dart, dart-async

Is it possible to create a custom implementation of the abstract class `Future`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending or implementing `Future` is prevented to allow several performance optimizations which wouldn't be possible otherwise.

The package [async](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async) provides a `DelegatingFuture` that can be extended instead and which delegates to another future.

For more details see the discussion at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24335